# Software Copy Protection & Licensing

Tags: windows-10, .net

I am looking for a product that will allow us to properly license our .NET applications. We have mostly WPF apps, but we also have a few ASP.NET Web Forms Applications that are deployed to servers and sold to our customers for internal use. What we're looking for is a way to "lock down" the software once it is installed, to ensure that even if the files are copied (or the HD is cloned) and installed on a different PC, that without a new license from us, it won't work.

Edited to add: we have, in the past, used Sentinel keys for one of our products. However, we're looking more for a software solution, that will work across the .NET spectrum.

Comment: Are your customers likely to deliberately try to steal your software? Or are they more likely to 'accidentally' install more seats than they've licensed? Could a system that phones home to tell you how it's being used be useful? (you could then just bill them for any 'extra' installs that show up).

Comment: We've had a few instances where a customer has tried to purchase their own PC and copy our software over to it without an additional license. Normally they purchase the PC and software and everything directly from us. Being able to connect and check in with a server would be a good option, but internet connectivity is kinda sketchy for some of them sometimes. Some are in fairly remote locations.